# accepts_nested_attributes not saving any changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, nested-attributes

Maybe I'm missing something obvious (hopefully), but I'm encountering a weird problem saving records in a nested form. It's a pretty basic setup, with a minor complication in that my LineItem model is a two-word relationship (:line_items). However, I've followed Rails guidelines and it seems to be working OK.

My fixtures are creating the proper relationships between line_items and invoices, and everything is showing up properly in my views, but I can't get any line_item records to save correctly (in my Rails console or my views).

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :line_items  #and the rest of my relevant attributes
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items, :allow_destroy => true
  # Rest of my model code
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :invoice_id  #and the rest of my relevant attributes
  belongs_to :invoice  
end
```

The `line_items_attributes=` method exists for my Invoices, but it doesn't save any line_items for new invoices. More irritating, I can edit existing line_items or assign them after the fact, but not in one fell swoop (the whole point of nested attributes?). My views can't even edit existing line_items through the invoice form. Any ideas? Happy to post more code, but didn't for sake of brevity.

Thanks in advance...

VIEW CODE (by request):

(Form Partial for Invoices)

```
<%= form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
  <% @invoice.line_items.build unless @invoice.line_items.any? %>
  ...
  <% f.fields_for :line_items do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'line_item_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
```

(Form Partial for Line Items)

```
...
<%= f.collection_select :sku_id, @skus, :id, :name, :prompt => true %>
<%= f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)") %>
```

(javascript)

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).previous("input[type=hidden]").value = "1";
  $(link).up(".fields").hide();
}
```

Comment: Please show your view-code. Are you using `fields_for`?

Comment: Wow, I haven't been able to spot anything wrong with the code you've posted.  I'm leaning toward thinking this is an object issue, nothing to do with the controller or view layers. I don't have time to dig into this now, hopefully someone else can jump in.  Have you attempted to set attributes in console?  If it fails, you have a model issue. If it succeeds, the issue is in the controller/view.  Good luck, and I'll check back later.

Comment: @Jaime: The console is acting super weird. I can create an invoice and set attributes for a new 'line_item' or several. When I actually save, validations pass, but no line_items are created (so I'm left with an empty invoice and no notification that anything went wrong). I cannot manipulate or destroy anything in my views. I'm going crazy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely culprit here is attr_accessible. When you use accepts_nested_attributes_for, the name of the attribute for an association is association_attributes. So you want

```
attr_accessible :line_items_attributes
```

instead of

```
attr_accessible :line_items
```

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to do the trick in my Views. Not sure if it's fixed everything, but working so far. I didn't think I'd have to manually add that to the list - I assumed that nested_attributes would take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Please list your view code, because your bug may be in how you're calling your nested forms.  Here's my primer on nested attributes, if it helps:

http://kconrails.com/2010/10/19/common-addresses-using-polymorphism-and-nested-attributes-in-rails/

Following this guide may take care of your problem.

Comment: I've seen your blog before, thanks for taking a look. I'll check out your code and see if I can figure out where I screwed up...